# Possible to hilight specific text (like user-defined words) in rstudio?

Tags: rstudio

With theme option, it's quite convenient to edit on rstudio, especially the highlighted keywords, is it possible to add user-defined keywords? as the number `1` and `function`.

[image]

Comment: Refer This : https://community.rstudio.com/t/syntax-highlighting-for-additional-filetypes/1485/3

Comment: seems not yet provided. Thanks.